# getUserMedia() audio - POST to webserver?

Tags: javascript, html, microphone

Can you POST data to a URL/webserver after microphone audio capture with getUserMedia()?  I have seen examples of how to use GuM, but they always reference "stream" and never do anything with it; I would like to know if I can POST that audio data to a webserver after the recording is stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to this article : http://www.smartjava.org/content/record-audio-using-webrtc-chrome-and-speech-recognition-websockets